# MySQL query to return 1 and 0 based on difference between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-dependent-subquery

In MySQL Database I have a table ABC  that consists of a column 'LastDate'.

**LastDate** which has datatype as DATETIME. The default value for this 'NULL'

I need to write a query for the table which would
Return '1' in these cases.
1) If DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME,LastDate) is >15 or if DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME,LastDate) is
NULL(i.e defaultVal).

return '0' if DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME,LastDate) is <15.

I tried to write an SQL query for this but was unable to do it. Please help me write this Query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update the question to show your SQL attempt.  Hint, ```SELECT CASE END ...``` might be an option.

Comment: is there a particular row in ABC that you are testing?  or you want your 0/1 results for each row?

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit about your logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME, LastDate) > 15 or
                  LastDate is null
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```

This can be simplified to:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME, LastDate) <= 15, 1) as flag
from t;
```